# Is the existence of Banach limits independent of ZF+DC?

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, real-analysis

Is the existence of Banach limits independent of ZF+DC?

Assuming this is known, where can I find a proof?

Comment: See Theorem 44 [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/2010.15632)

Comment: @Wojowu. Thank you.

Comment: @Wojowu: I was going to say that! :-)

Comment: @Wojowu's [reference](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/417300/is-the-existence-of-banach-limits-independent-of-zfdc#comment1070941_417300):  [Karagila - Zornian Functional Analysis or: How I Learned to Stop Worrying and Love the Axiom of Choice](https://arxiv.org/abs/2010.15632).

Comment: @Asaf. In the preface to your paper you say the results contained therein are essentially from the literature. Who might reasonably be regarded as the (an) author of Theorem 44.

Comment: @PhilipEhrlich: Hmm. I can't really remember, to be fair. This result will either appear directly in Eric S. Schechter's book, probably with a proper reference, or it will be easily found through Google Scholar or something like that. If I had to guess, I'd say either Banach himself noted something like that to be true or maybe it was in one of the many works of Pincus and Solovay on these topics. But I wouldn't be shocked to learn that Kuratowski or Sierpinski were the actual observers. Martin Väth hangs around here sometimes, maybe he'll know.

Comment: @Asaf.Thank you. The proof you offer is lovely.

Comment: In [section 4.1 of this article](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2272118), Solovay and Pincus constructed a model of ZF + DC in which there are no finitely additive probability measures vanishing on singletons on $\mathcal{P}(X)$ for any set $X$. This implies that no infinite discrete group has a Banach measure (not just countable ones). The statement that BP $\Rightarrow$ no nonprincipal measures on $\omega$ was stated by Solovay at the top of p. 3 of his most famous article and [Pincus](https://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BFb0066014) gave a proof starting on p. 207.

Comment: @Fuber. Thanks for the references.

Comment: Thanks, Philip! I had a great deal of joy in working this literature review.